# Removed custom post type slug but not working for child pages

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, child-pages, regex

There are many discussions going about to handle child pages for custom post types were the custom post type slug has been removed. This results into an 404 because Wordpress can't match a valid regex.

As far as I tried and read almost every single post about this problem on internet I still couldn't find the solution. If there is a solution to this problem I would like to check this one out to solve my problem.

If there is not an direct known solution to this problem I was asking myself if it could be possible to do a regex on this to make it work anyway?

I have my custom post type as services but I would like to be able to receive my pages as **host/programming/** or **host/programming/front-end/** were front-end is a child page of programming . This is an example but in all situation I checked out on the internet the child page 'front-end' will turn up in an 404 page not found.

Hopefully we can clear out some stuffs about these situations. Many thanks!